# CorePlot with Swift - bringing axis to the front

Tags: swift, ios8, core-plot, swift2, ios9

So, I am converting one of my projects that uses CorePlot to Swift. I have a graph that in addition to regular x- and y-axis I add two more. By default, the axis were hidden by the graph. I used the following code in Objective-C to show them over graph:

```
graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea.topDownLayerOrder = @[@(CPTGraphLayerTypeAxisLines)];
```

Here is what it looks like:
[image]

I was wondering how do I do that in Swift? I can't seem to set **topDownLayerOrder** without getting some sort of "can't assign to [AnyObject]!" message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of the co-worker, this is what we came up with:

```
graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea.topDownLayerOrder = [CPTGraphLayerType.AxisLines.rawValue]
```

Comment: In CorePlot 2.2 and Swift 4, this would now be

```graph.plotAreaFrame?.plotArea?.topDownLayerOrder = [NSNumber(value:CPTGraphLayerType.axisLines.rawValue)]```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea.topDownLayerOrder = [CPTGraphLayerType.AxisLines.rawValue]
```